# I am trying to install docker. Whenever i run sudo apt-get update, i get this error:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, docker

Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease

Get:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [3,316 B]

Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease

Ign:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease

Hit:4 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease

Hit:5 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease

Fetched 3,316 B in 4s (774 B/s)

Reading package lists... Done

W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45

W: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.debian.org/spotify, you need to add the key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4773BD5E130D1D45
```

Then just remove the duplicates from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list` or remove the file entirely.